# Creating universal settings for WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that I'm creating and I'm currently working on a setting window. Now I save all persistent data to a local SQL Lite DB. Let's say I decide to set a color scheme option or an opacity option to make it simple. How would I make this setting apply to every WPF Window?

Is there an easier way than going through every window's initialized event and changing it there?

My question is different from the possible duplicate because its not just theme but other settings as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change theme at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229724/change-theme-at-runtime)

Comment: You could create a common style in a resource dictionary that will be applied to all windows